# If $w_1=a_1+ib_1$ and $w_2=a_2+ib_2$ are complex numbers, then $|e^{w_1}-e^{w_2}|\geq e^{a_1}-e^{a_2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers, absolute-value

Let $w_1=a_1+ib_1$ and $w_2=a_2+ib_2$ be two complex numbers.

Ahlfors says that $|e^{w_1}-e^{w_2}|\geq e^{a_1}-e^{a_2}$.

I don't understand why that is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please make sure your title describes the mathematical content of your question. There are dozens of questions from Ahlfors' book here. See the advice on [asking good questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\bigl||x|-|y|\bigr|\leq |x-y|$ (the reverse triangle inequality) holds for complex numbers $x,y$.